# Spring LDAP 2.0.2 - No Injection (or how to inject) - @Autowired

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-security, spring-ldap

I am new to Spring LDAP (the version I am using is: 2.0.2) and I have some questions. I am querying Active Directory.

I am going to post my code, and my questions are in my main class - **MainLdapTest**:

**ldap_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans     xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">

    <!-- Information about this configuration file can be found:
            http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#configuration
    -->
    <ldap:context-source id="contextSource"
                         url="ldap://<url>:<port>"
                         base="DC=comp,DC=com"
                         username="<username>"
                         password="<secret>" />

    <ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" context-source-ref="contextSource" />

    <bean id="LdapUserDAO" class="com.ldap.dao.LdapUserDAOImpl">
        <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**LdapUser.java**

```
@Entry(objectClasses = {"top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "user"})
public final class LdapUser {
    @Id
    private Name distinguishedName;

    @Attribute(name="cn")
    private String cn;

    @Attribute(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Attribute(name="displayName")
    private String displayName;

    @Attribute(name="sAMAccountName")
    private String sAMAccountName;

    @Attribute(name="mail")
    private String mail;

    @Attribute(name="userPrincipalName")
    private String userPrincipalName;

    @Attribute(name="userAccountControl")
    private String userAccountControl;
    // ...
    // getters and setters
    // ...
```

**LdapUserDAO.java**

```
public interface LdapUserDAO
{
    public LdapUser create(LdapUser ldapUser);
    public void update(LdapUser ldapUser);
    public void delete(LdapUser ldapUser);
    public LdapUser findByUid(String uid);
    public List<LdapUser> findAll();
    public List<LdapUser> findByLastName(String lastName);
    public List<LdapUser> findBySAMAccountName(String sAMAccountName);
    public List<LdapUser> findDisabledUsers();
    public List<LdapUser> findDisabledUser(LdapUser ldapUser);
    public List<LdapUser> findByObjectClassPerson();
    public void setLdapTemplate(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate);
}
```

**LdapUserDAOImpl.java**

```
public class LdapUserDAOImpl implements LdapUserDAO
{
    @Autowired
    private LdapTemplate localLdapTemplate;
    // ...
    public List<LdapUser> findBySAMAccountName(String sAMAccountName) {
        return localLdapTemplate.find(query().where("sAMAccountName").is(sAMAccountName), LdapUser.class);
    }
    // ...
```

**MainLdapTest.java**

```
public class MainLdapTest
{
    @Autowired
    private LdapUserDAO ldapUserDao;

    public MainLdapTest() {
        /**
         * The ldap_config.xml above is in my classpath, 
         * but how do I specify that the contents of that file must be used to inject ldapTemplate in this class, or any other class?
         *
         * Below are my tests and their result:
         *
         * Tests
         * 1. This test returns a NullPointerException because ldapTemplate is not set.
         *    Shouldn't it be injected by the "@Autowired" annotation?
         */
        List<LdapUser> queryListError = ldapUserDao.findByObjectClassPerson();
        System.out.println("[ERR] Query returns no values[queryListRetValues]: #[" + queryListError.size() + "]");

        /**
         * 2. As I set the LdapContextSource manually, it returns the data searched in the query.
         *
         *    sAMAccountName is the <username>
         */
        LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();
        ctxSrc.setUrl("<url>");
        ctxSrc.setBase("<base>");
        ctxSrc.setUserDn("<username>");
        ctxSrc.setPassword("<password>");
        ctxSrc.afterPropertiesSet();

        ldapUserDao = new LdapUserDAOImpl(ldapTemplate);
        List<LdapUser> queryListRetValues = ldapUserDao.findBySAMAccountName("<username>");
        System.out.println("[OK] Query returns no values[queryListRetValues]: #[" + queryListRetValues.size() + "]");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MainLdapTest t = new MainLdapTest();
    }
}
```

In fact, my code is based on the one in **Spring LDAP - ODM [1]**. I have used the **"@Autowired"** annotation and as I understand the LdapTemplate should be injected into my LdapUserDAOImpl.

I know there is a basic error here, I just can't find where.

As I was not sure if I should only post the link, but I have asked the same question in the spring forum [2].

Links:
[[1-Spring Ldap Reference]](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/#odm)
[[2-Spring Forum Question]](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/ldap/749814-spring-ldap-2-0-2-no-injection-or-how-to-inject-autowired)

Thanks for your attention and help.

Regards!

Comment: I think your autowiring isn't effective. Instead of creating the bean on XML, try `<context:component-scan ...>` and add `@Component` annotation to LdapDAOImpl

Comment: I don't think the autowiring is not effective, because, as I understand, this is how spring ldap works. I have checked all the samples shipped with the package, and looks like it is auto wired. One sample class that shows this is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/samples/odm/src/test/java/org/springframework/ldap/samples/odm/dao/PersonDaoSampleIntegrationTest.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sorry** about the long time without updates/answer!

The answer is quite simple, in order to "load" the beans in the XML, you need to do:

```
final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
```

And after, get the bean from context:

```
LdapProvider ldapProvider = (LdapProvider) context.getBean(LdapProvider.class);
```

Thanks for all the help! And hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that any object that is annotated with `@Autowired` need to be created by Spring so that Spring can actually inject the object. To get it to work, you should update to be the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:ldap_config.xml")
public class MainLdapTest
    @Autowired
    private LdapUserDAO ldapUserDao;

    @Test
    public run() {
        /**
         * The ldap_config.xml above is in my classpath, 
         * but how do I specify that the contents of that file must be used to inject ldapTemplate in this class, or any other class?
         *
         * Below are my tests and their result:
         *
         * Tests
         * 1. This test returns a NullPointerException because ldapTemplate is not set.
         *    Shouldn't it be injected by the "@Autowired" annotation?
         */
        List<LdapUser> queryListError = ldapUserDao.findByObjectClassPerson();
        System.out.println("[ERR] Query returns no values[queryListRetValues]: #[" + queryListError.size() + "]");

        /**
         * 2. As I set the LdapContextSource manually, it returns the data searched in the query.
         *
         *    sAMAccountName is the <username>
         */
        LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();
        ctxSrc.setUrl("<url>");
        ctxSrc.setBase("<base>");
        ctxSrc.setUserDn("<username>");
        ctxSrc.setPassword("<password>");
        ctxSrc.afterPropertiesSet();

        ldapUserDao = new LdapUserDAOImpl(ldapTemplate);
        List<LdapUser> queryListRetValues = ldapUserDao.findBySAMAccountName("<username>");
        System.out.println("[OK] Query returns no values[queryListRetValues]: #[" + queryListRetValues.size() + "]");
    }
}
```

This assumes that ldap_config.xml, junit.jar, and spring-test.jar are on your classpath.

This will work because the `SpringJunit4ClassRunner` will load your Spring configuration and ensure to inject the `LdapUserDAO` for you.

If you are running in a standard Servlet environment, then you will want to ensure Spring creates your objects there too.

Of course if you do not want to use Spring's dependency injection you can create the LDapUserDAO by injecting its dependencies programmatically.

Comment: Sorry to put comments here only today, after some days! Thanks for the comment. As I commented, I am not a spring expert, so, please, correct me if I am wrong, the code above is to be used for Tests only, right? And if I want it not to Tests only? What I need to do to make it run in a standalone and a J2EE enviroment? Thanks a lot for your help!